# How can I display something during the execution of a SQL script on SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, echo, notify

For example. I have a database upgrade script for adding a column to a database table. It looks a little like this:

```
IF NOT Exists(SELECT * FROM SysColumns sc, SysObjects so 
              WHERE sc.Name = 'dealer_number'  
              AND so.Name = 'collector'
              AND so.Type= 'U'
              AND so.id = sc.id)
BEGIN
 -- SQL for creating column
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 -- notify user that column already exists
END
```

How do I notify the user that the column already exists?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
RAISERROR ('column already exists',0,1)  with nowait
```

or

```
print 'column already exists'
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) statement in SQL

Answer (score 2):

Use *PRINT* - it works from most SQL client applications. *SELECT* also works
e.g

```
PRINT 'column already exists or something'
```

or

```
SELECT 'column already exists or something'
```

Answer (score 2):

RAISERROR seems appropriate here. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx).