# SQL Server 2008 - Retrieving message when procedures ends running

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display something during the execution of a SQL script on SQLServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700106/how-can-i-display-something-during-the-execution-of-a-sql-script-on-sqlserver)

I have multiple procedures being run in the same query. I'd like a specific message to be printed when each procedure finishes running.

How can I do that?

I tried to do

```
PRINT 'message'
```

at the end of each procedure, but it just prints all the messages at the same time when they are all over.